# Button is vanishing after putting canvas tag using HTML

Tags: html, canvas

I have an issue .my buttons are not visible after putting the canvas tag using HTML.I am explaining my code below.

```
<form name="frmpromotion" id="frmpromotion" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<div class="col-md-8">
  <div class="couponimg" id="nonblankimagediv">
  <img class="img-responsive thumbnail" style="margin-bottom:9px;" src="images/coupon-banner.jpg" crossorigin="anonymous">
</div>
<div class="couponimg" style="display:none;" id="blankImagediv">
<img class="img-responsive thumbnail" style="margin-bottom:9px;" src="images/coupon-banner-blank.jpg" crossorigin="anonymous">
 </div>
</div>
<canvas id="canvas" />
<div class="col-md-12 text-center bloginbuttondevider">  
<div class="form-group">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary bloginbtn" name="coupon_submit" id="btncouponsubmit">Add</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn bloginbtn cancelbtn" name="coupon_submit" id="btncouponcancel">Cancel</button>
</div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Here i put canvas Html tag and suddenly those two buttons are not displaying. When i removed canvas those two button are coming. Here i need the canvas tag.So please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add separate canvas closing tag after canvas tag:

```
<canvas id="canvas" > </canvas>
```

Comment: : Like how ? Please check your post.

Comment: `<canvas id="canvas" > </canvas>`